# Facebook Graph API - event_state_filter parameter returns no data for scheduled events

Tags: javascript, facebook, http, facebook-graph-api

I'm stuck with a weird Facebook Graph API issue: I have a test Facebook Page where I created many events with different settings (different date values, names, descriptions, etc) for testing purposes.

I'm managing to get all events from requests made to the page (via {page}/events), except for scheduled events.

I created one event that was scheduled to be posted in the future. I tried requesting that event by using the **event_state_filter** parameter, as follows:

> https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/{page-id}/events?access_token={token}&event_state_filter=['draft','scheduled_draft_for_publication']

Here's a screenshot of the scheduled post for that Facebook Page.

[Scheduled Event on Facebook Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELruT.png)

It returns data for published/cancelled events if I include 'published' or 'cancelled', but not for draft/scheduled events. Any ideas?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code is correct. I have a page with a draft event, a scheduled event and a published event and the scheduled ones don't return. I'd perhaps consider opening a bug with FB to get confirmation.

Comment: Hey Patrick, thanks for the reply. Since you're also experiencing the same issue on your side, I'm going to try and report this to Facebook.

Comment: Sounds good. I tried it with user access token of an admin of the page, and a page access token for the page and neither returned the value. Didn't see anything in changelogs indicating changes to events either

Comment: Hmm... Looks like it might be a bug indeed. I have submitted a bug report regarding the issue: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1399270483510365